# Match log level from a properties file with Enum set for logging levels and display log according to hierarchy

Tags: java, logging, enums

In my logger class

```
public enum LogLevel {
    NOLOG("6") , ERROR("5"), WARN("4"), INFO("3"), DEBUG("2"), TRACE("1") ;}
```

I want to be able to read the log level from a properties file and match it here in the logger class , and my application should write log to the db using the loglevels.
Supposing its in NOLOG -> No logging happens
if its Debug --> Error,Warn ,Info and Debug happens and so on.

I am able to write log messages to db and read the log level from properties file.

**How to match it to the enums in my logger class and then display the log messages on hierarchy?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a static Factory method like this:

```
public enum LogLevel {
    NOLOG("6") , ERROR("5"), WARN("4"), INFO("3"), DEBUG("2"), TRACE("1") ;

    private Integer value;

    LogLevel(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static LogLevel levelOf(Integer value) {
        for (LogLevel level : LogLevel.values()) {
            if (level.value.equals(value)) {
                return level;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When you get a value from the property file, you can  get LogLevel Object naturally:

```
LogLevel level = LogLevel.levelOf(somePropertyObject.getIntValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have if-elif statements. You can get the int value from the enum by doing

```
Logleve.NOLOG.ordinal()
```

Read log level from a properties file, compare it here in the enum file and then update the logger property to that level.

Also, is there a reason you are not using Java's in-built logger or log4j?